# connect/checksession infinite loop identity server 4 v4 asp.net core with react application

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using Identity server 4 v4 with react application to do Authorization and Authentication. However, after the login from the identity server in the network tab I can see the to request as infinite

https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration
and https://localhost:5001/connect/checksession

I don't know what is the reason that causing the infinite.

Here is the client setting

```
 return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "Local",
                    ClientName = "Local",
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = LocalRedirectUris(),
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AccessTokenLifetime=86400,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                    RedirectUris = LocalRedirectUris(),
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = LocalRedirectUris(),
                    AllowedScopes = AllowedScopes(),
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    //AllowRememberConsent = true
                }
            };
```

React application setting

```
return {
            authority: "https://localhost:5001",
            client_id: "Local",
            redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5001/auth-callback",
            post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5001",
            response_type: "code",
            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            scope: "profile openid email offline_access",
            //filterProtocolClaims: environment.openID.filterProtocolClaims,
            loadUserInfo: true,
            monitorSession: true,
            silent_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5001/silent-reniew.html",
            accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 20, //default 60
            //checkSessionInterval: 86400, //default 2000
            //silentRequestTimeout: 2000,
        };

 Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint for /connect/checksession
```

Comment: Try setting AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime for client

Comment: Didn't work AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 86400

Comment: Were you able to figure out your issue? I've had a strange thing happen in that I did a windows update and ever since I'm in an infinite loop. Exact same code base on other's machines does not experience this so head scraching.